# Investment Accounts in My Name

Tags: investment-income

My father-in-law has opened and manages several investment accounts in my husband's name.  From time to time he has offered to invest my husband's money in the accounts but has always stated that the money was "lost".

We are trying to find out what accounts were opened in my husband's name. Using the state searches for old accounts will not work since my father-in-law  is still active in these accounts. Is there another way to search?

Comment: Presumably the accounts have his social security number on them? Do you receive tax documents for the accounts?

Comment: Sounds like this is a legal question... things might get very dicey, very quickly.

Comment: *but has always stated the money was "lost".*  Your FIL keeps saying that he **lost** your husband's money?  If that interpretation is true, then either your FIL is incompetent or fraudulent.